# append checkbox not show after ajax called

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have a problem with displaying my checkbox. My checkbox is dynamic, and append checkbox after ajax success function. But i dont'w know it won't display at all.
This is my html html and ajax code

```
<fieldset id="appendfilter" style="margin-top: 5px;">

</fieldset>

boelanCek = true;
$.ajax({
    url: host+'/skripsi3/phpmobile/appendfilter.php',
    data: { "id": id},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data, status){
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
            alert("here");
            if(item.dicek=="ya")
            {
                if (boelanCek)
                {

                    if (arrCekbox.indexOf(item.idkategori)<0)
                    {   

                        $("#appendfilter").append('<input class="kategoriFilter" checked="checked" type="checkbox" value="'+item.nama+'" name="cektambah" id="'+item.idkategori+'"><label for="'+item.idkategori+'">'+item.nama+'</label>');    
                        arrCekbox.push(item.idkategori);

                    }

                    boelanCek=false;
                }
                else
                {
                        if (arrCekbox.indexOf(item.idkategori)<0)
                        {
                            $("#appendfilter").prepend('<input class="kategoriFilter" checked="checked" type="checkbox" value="'+item.nama+'" name="cektambah" id="'+item.idkategori+'"><label for="'+item.idkategori+'">'+item.nama+'</label>');   
                            arrCekbox.push(item.idkategori);
                        }
                }
                $('#appendfilter').checkboxradio('refresh');
            }
            else if(item.dicek=="tidak")
            {
                if (boelanCek)
                {

                    if (arrCekbox.indexOf(item.idkategori)<0)
                    {   

                        $("#appendfilter").append('<input class="kategoriFilter" type="checkbox" value="'+item.nama+'" name="cektambah" id="'+item.idkategori+'"><label for="'+item.idkategori+'">'+item.nama+'</label>');  
                        arrCekbox.push(item.idkategori);

                    }

                    boelanCek=false;
                }
                else
                {
                        if (arrCekbox.indexOf(item.idkategori)<0)
                        {
                            $("#appendfilter").prepend('<input class="kategoriFilter" type="checkbox" value="'+item.nama+'" name="cektambah" id="'+item.idkategori+'"><label for="'+item.idkategori+'">'+item.nama+'</label>'); 
                            arrCekbox.push(item.idkategori);
                        }
                }
                $('#appendfilter').checkboxradio('refresh');
            }

        });
    },
    error: function(){
        //output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
    }
});
```

this inside appendfilter.php

```
<?php
 session_start();
include "config.php";
$user=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["user"]);
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * from filtering WHERE id_tenant='$user'") or die(mysql_error());

if (!empty($result))
{
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $tempfilter[] = $row['filter'];
        $q="select 'iya' as dicek,kategori.id_kategori,kategori.nama from kategori WHERE id_kategori  IN (".implode(',',$tempfilter).") UNION ALL select 'tidak' as dicek,kategori.id_kategori,kategori.nama from kategori where id_kategori  NOT IN (".implode(',',$tempfilter).") ";


        //echo $q;
        $result2 = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
        if (!empty($result2))
        {
            while ($row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2))
            {
                $fetchkategori[] = array
                (
                    'nama' => $row2['nama'],
                    'idkategori' => $row2['id_kategori'],
                    'dicek' => $row2["dicek"]
                );  
            }
        }

    }
}



mysql_close($con);

header('Content-Type:application/json');
echo json_encode($fetchkategori);
?>
```

Maybe someone can help me . Thank you guys and have a nice day!! Cheers!!

Comment: You are passing id using data: { "id": id},....But in PHP code expecting user field like this: $user=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["user"]);...No idea where do you use id in PHP ?

Comment: You need to start by doing some basic debugging to figure out if any of your `.append()` commands are even being run.

Comment: hey @MaheshChavda thank you for your  response, i have changed it but it still didn't work.